# Software for social reading

Tags: android, ios, facebook, social-networks, books

I am looking for an app for Android and iOS smartphones and PCs that implements social reading. This is an app where several books, such as the ones taught in middle schools high schools and universities, as well as others, are available.

In the app you can select books, or upload your own, and select friends that you can make friends with after you can search for them as in Facebook.

In the main part of the interface, the screen in divided into three areas.

- In the top area, you read a book

Here you can highlight parts of the book in colors, selecting the given color for the highlight.

This is my private reading area of the book.

- In the middle portion, an initially blank text editing area appears for the highlighted text. The background is the same color as the selected highlight. Here you can add and exit text for that highlight. This is the second half of the screen.

You can attach profile smileys to the highlights, corresponding to your friends. These are the same icons as the ones that appear in your Google profile in the top right of Google keep. They are not true smileys, but profile pictures surrounded by a round circle, and they are small enough to fit in the text, next to a highlight.

This means the situation reminds you of an embedding (actual or desired), of your friend, in the situation, or perhaps your imagine your friend extending the text with some imagination, opinion.

This is how many thoughts about socializing mingle with the text I read when I read it.

- In the bottom area, besides each friend smiley (as they were added), you can put the relevant questions you want to ask the friend (as associated with each highlight and then with each smiley).

You keep on reading.

When you want (the friend may put you on hold if they are reading), you post your highlights, to the given friends. When you post your hilight to the given friend or friends, you select the per-friend-group comment in the second half and post it to your friends. Think of it as friends in a reading room. Alternatively, the comments for the book may be public if the book is public, otherwise it is just available to the people involved in purchasing the book for common reading (you may find more pleasure of your have purchased the book for reading with someone, or even if within the friends list all people involved who have purchased the book are available). Sharing book parts outside of the network is prohibited if not allowed by the authors, or, publishers.
However, it is important that social reading is implemented, because this is how books are read and enjoyed in the classroom, and people, after, school, will have a natural drive, and desire, to engage, in such manner (they would even read more and be more motivated to read if this were implemented).

In this bottom part, ceckmarks appear, next to each friend, you posted the highlight to.

....

So, in this app, your read a book.

But can engage and embed, your friends, in the brain, generated (by the reading experience.

The friend may reply to each posted comment, within each book (and this is also available in a feed, globally).

You may reply to what the friend, says, about your post, in a book reference-specific chat.

You can engage the friends you want in each section of the book you want (the ones that come to mind or with whom you want to engage the text with, while, reading).

The book purchased may be even decoupled from the social network book reading app (a purchase can be plugged into more than one social network, perhaps, with each social network working slightly differently).

Where can I find such a social reading and messaging app?

Is anyone willing to implement this?

That would be nice.

Thank you for your support.